# Create android project using command line with jars in Libs folder

Tags: java, android, eclipse, jar, libs

When i went through the Android documentation, it says that the following Command would create an android project.

```
android create project
--target <target_ID>
--name <your_project_name>
--path path/to/your/project
--activity <your_activity_name>
--package <your_package_namespace>
```

This works perfect. But i couldn't find android support jar in Libs folder. When i create the same project using eclipse, by default the android support jar is added to Libs folder. But I want to include the JARs in the command so that they can be added to Libs folder at once. Is there any command like that where i can add the list of JARs as arguments in the Command and while creating project the JARs would be added to Libs folder? Or is this possible using any of the eclipse Command line tool of creating a java project with JARs added to dist folder or any such kind?

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible with standard Android command tools. You will have to copy them manually from android SDK.

Comment: Do we have any command line tool for eclipse just to create a normal java project and copy the list of jars to the dist like folder in the project using any command? Please suggest

Comment: If you can use Android command I assume you have access to command line. Then you can just use standard your OS copy function. I don't which OS you are using, but for Windows this might help [link](http://www.wikihow.com/Copy-Files-in-Command-Prompt)